# Auto add amount with decimal value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to appear in (total amount) automatically the sum of (Amount Paid and OtherCharges) how can I do that?

I'm getting incorrect value in total amount, let say

Amount Paid = 100.90

Other Charges = 10.1

Total Amount = 100.91

here's my code

```
 $('#AmountPaid, #OtherCharges, #Amount').on('input',function() {

    var AmountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()).toFixed(2);
    var OtherCharges = parseFloat($('#OtherCharges').val()).toFixed(2);
    var Amount =  parseFloat($('#Amount').val()).toFixed(2);  


    $('#Amount').val(parseFloat(AmountPaid + OtherCharges)).toFixed(2);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

`toFixed` turns your number back into a string. When you `+` two strings together, you get a concatenated string, like `100.9010.1`. Then you're `parseFloat`ing that, which will disregard the invalid part and give you `100.901`, which you're `toFixed`'ing, which rounds. I'm not sure why you'd get `100.91` for your inputs (I get `100.90`), but fundamentally those are the issues.

The solution is to pay close attention to when you're dealing with *strings* vs. *numbers*. Also, you probably don't want to hook `input` on your **output** field (`#Amount`), just your *input* fields.

So:

```
$('#AmountPaid, #OtherCharges').on('input', function() {
    var AmountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val());
    var OtherCharges = parseFloat($('#OtherCharges').val());
    var Amount =  AmountPaid + OtherCharges;

    $('#Amount').val(Amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('#AmountPaid, #OtherCharges').on('input', function() {
  var AmountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val());
  var OtherCharges = parseFloat($('#OtherCharges').val());
  var Amount = AmountPaid + OtherCharges;

  $('#Amount').val(Amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<p>Fill in either of the first two fields, and the third is updated:</p>
<label>
  Amount paid:
  <input type="text" id="AmountPaid" value="100.90">
</label>
<label>
  Other charges:
  <input type="text" id="OtherCharges" value="">
</label>
<label>
  Amount:
  <input type="text" id="Amount" value="">
</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

And a general caveat around using JavaScript's numbers for financial calculations: [*Is floating point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)